# Images do not show up using .css file

Tags: css

I downloaded a free template and I want to use it for my web site (using c# in Visual Studio 2010). I put  inside the  tag, but it shows me only one color, without the images. I put image folder, style.css file and index.html in the same hierarchy in the project.

Comment: We will need to see what code you have to help

Comment: I downloaded template and I insert image folder, style.css file and index.html. And I do the following:
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Pocetna.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pocetna" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Добродојдовте</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    
    </form>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit your original question and use code formatting. Nobody wants to read code like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Pocetna.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pocetna" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;

 <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; 
    <head runat="server">
      <title>Добродојдовте</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/style.css" />
    </head>
   <body> 
   <form id="form1" runat="server">  </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS which you have copied is having relative path for images.
You will be required to either change paths to absolute path or needs to copy images from remote place(from where you have copied css) and put it into required place in local directory

Answer (score 0):

do you use firefox or chrome? Use the web developer tool to see that your page is really saying. Then you may get the idea where is the error happening.

Comment: I used them both. And I only see one color- the backgorund color of the template

Comment: can you please upload your file somewhere and give us the link? Its nearly impossible without actually seeing your problem.